# How to change the ListView size dynamically in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistview

I have tried:

```
self.listView.setResizeMode(QtWidgets.QListView.Adjust)
```

I want my listView to show more content if the parent widget is stretched vertically. It shows more content if i expand the parent widget horizontally but vertically it doesn't expand.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Given that your QListView's name is **listview**. Try this :

```
sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(6)
sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(listView.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
listView.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
```